# Set variable in Jinja throwing error

Tags: django, jinja2

I am trying to get the values of keys in dictionary in jinja.

```
{% for key, values in chat_data.items %}

           {{values.from}} <br/>
           <b> Query: </b>{{values.init_query}}<br/>
           {% for k in values.chat %}
               {% set last_response = '111' %}
           {% endfor %} 
           {{last_response}}
{% endfor%}
```

Error : `Invalid block tag: 'set', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'`

How can I set the variable in Jinja

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Jinja2 built-in `last()` filter?

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#last

i.e. try:

```
{% for key, values in chat_data.items %}
       {{values.from}} <br/>
       <b> Query: </b>{{values.init_query}}<br/>
       {{ values.chat|last }}
{% endfor%}
```

Using `set` should still work though.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **last_response** outside for loop.

You can use the Jinja2 built-in [**last()**](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#last) filter instead of for with set

```
{{ values.chat | last }}
```